# Apply a class inside paragraph with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have got a problem with Ruby on Rails template using HAML.

I have no idea how to apply a specific class inside a tag, for example in:

```
%p My name is John Doe
```

I want to add a .highlight class to "name" word. How to do this? I only know this way:

```
%p
    %span My
    %span.highlight name
    %span is John Doe
```

but of course it is not the best way to do this, I hope so. Any ideas?

Comment: You have add the class to the `span`, now with CSS, you can apply styles to the text which is contained inside the `span` tag..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No matter what, you have to put the highlighted text in its own element, so your code is pretty close. You don't need to wrap the rest of the text in elements, though:

```
%p
  My
  %span.highlight name
  is John Doe
```

This will produce:

```html
<p>
  My
  <span class="highlight">name</span>
  is John Doe
</p>
```

**Edit:**

In the case of question marks, you can use Haml's `succeed` helper method:

```
%p
  = succeed "?" do
    What's your
    %span.highlight name
```

This will render:

```html
<p>
  What's your
  <span class='highlight'>name</span>?
</p>
```

There are also `precede` and `surround` methods, which you can read about here: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#helper-methods

If you'd rather use string interpolation, it's probably be easiest to define your own helper method.

```ruby
def hl(str)
  capture_haml {
    haml_tag 'span.highlight', escape_once(str)
  }.strip!.html_safe
end
```

Since this is kind of elaborate, let me break it down from the inside out. First, we need to escape the string with `escape_once`. This is only necessary if `str` comes from user input (and so could lead to an XSS attack), but it's good to have in any event. Then we use `haml_tag` to render the string inside a `span.highlight`. Then we have to capture this output as a string with `capture_haml`, since we're using it in interpolation (ordinarily `haml_tag` writes to the Haml buffer instead of returning a string). Then we use `strip!` because Haml will render a newline after this, and you said you don't want that. Finally, we use `html_safe` to tell Rails not to escape the output, since it would break our `<span>` and we already escaped the input so we know it's safe.

Now you can use the `hl` method in your interpolated Ruby:

```
%p
  What's your #{hl "name"}?
```

This will render:

```html
<p>
  What's your <span class='highlight'>name</span>?
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, after that apply CSS to give it a loon n feel.

Comment: I thought there was one-line way to do this, with something like #{...} or maybe not?
Of course your answer works, Jordan, but it automatically adds a space between these parts. Meanwhile if one of them is "?" I would like to avoid a space before it.

Comment: Good point, @MateuszKwaśniak. I've updated my answer with a couple ways to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh sir, I was stil looking for the answer and actually found one, refreshed this question and here is your update as well. The other answer is `%span> ?` to remove whitespace before question mark.
But thank you, now I know about precede/succeed and this #{...} thing is interpolation - yea, I forgot, thanks!

Comment: `%span> ?` will work, but will wrap your question mark in a `<span>`. More problematic is the fact that it will also remove whitespace *after* the question mark, so if it's followed by another sentence you'll have the same problem.